# Can I use an Encyclopedia as a reference in an essay?

Tags: citations, writing, writing-style, online-resource, liberal-arts-colleges

I am writing a paper that is about another culture. I need to include references about the culture in my paper. Is an encyclopedia an acceptable source for general information about the  culture (communication, nutrition, holidays, religion?)

Comment: Are you writing the paper for credit in a course?  If so, then the person grading your paper would be the one to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use an Encyclopedia as a reference in an essay?

**Yes, but, it mightn't be the best source.**

For instance, Britannica* has an entry on Coronavirus, as do many other encyclopedias. They probably aren't the most authoritative though. A better reference could be sought, e.g., the World Health Organization. The same is true for other topics, such as culture.

**An encyclopedia may give you what you need, but other sources might be more authoritative/better.**

<sup>* The first encyclopedia produced by a Google search.</sup>

Comment: As an addendum: if this encyclopedia's name is Wikipedia, the reader might have a bad impression.

Comment: @user111388 Indeed: I was using encyclopedia in the traditional sense.